# Finding matches between part of a cell and a range

Tags: excel

I'm using a `bloomberg` input formula to find the description of bond cusip (identification number for a bond).

So, one column I have: `=BDP(B1, SECURITY_DES)`
with a sample output of `ABC 4.0 05/05/2045`.

In another column, I have the maturity dates of certain bonds. For example:

```
05/5/2045
03/6/2019
02/28/2038
08/17/2025
```

How do I check if "5/5/2045" is in the column?

Answer (score 0):

To plainly just check if a text is inside another text you can use a countif function with a wildcard character `*`.  Something like:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"*"&B1)
```

(Where column B is your dates and column A is your sample output)

If this is greater than 0 then the date was found.  So if you want a true/false output you can say

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"*"&B1)>0
```

However looking at your *specific* case you are checking for `05/05/2045` but your date is listed as `05/5/2045` so that countif will not work unless you put it into the proper format.  I was able to work it by surrounding `B1` with a `TEXT` formula:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"*"&TEXT(B1,"mm/dd/yyyy"))
```

Again to get true/false:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"*"&TEXT(B1,"mm/dd/yyyy"))>0
```

And of course as before, column A as the sample output and Column B as the dates.  Just fill down as needed.